# Where are network config files supposed to be saved for libvirt?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-14.04, libvirt

I'm having a heck of a time with libvirt. I deleted the default NAT network, and I'm trying to add a Bridge for VMs. According to libvirt's wiki and [Network XML format | Using an existing host bridge](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#examplesBridge), I have the following:

```
<network>
    <name>host-bridge</name>
    <forward mode="bridge"/>
    <bridge name="br0"/>
</network>
```

I saved the file as ***`host-bridge.xml`***. I copied it to both ***`/etc/libvirt/`*** and ***`/usr/share/libvirt/schemas`***. However, regardless of what I try, I always get a:

```
$ sudo virsh net-create host-bridge
error: Failed to open file 'host-bridge': No such file or directory
$ sudo virsh net-create host-bridge.xml
error: Failed to open file 'host-bridge.xml': No such file or directory
```

The machine is running Ubuntu Server 14.03 LTS. According to ***`brctl`***, the bridge ***`br0`*** does exist, and its using ***`eth1`***.

Where are network config files supposed to be saved for libvirt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my (CentOS) based systems they are in `/var/lib/libvirt/network` (and this is the same for the [libvirt.org](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking) wiki answer)  but the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KvmWithBridge) suggests `/etc/libvirt/qemu` (in the libvirt guest Configuration section)

Answer (score 0):

To add to @davidgo's answer... I performed:

```
sudo mv /opt/libvirt/host-bridge.xml /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks
```

Once the network file is located where you want it:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/host-bridge.xml 
<network>
  <name>host-bridge</name>
  <uuid>88c0529e-4813-43fa-af27-01af164249ed</uuid>
  <forward mode='bridge'/>
  <bridge name='br0'/>
</network>
```

You still need to either (1) define it or (2) create it to *actually* use it in a VM. If you want it to be persistent, then you need to define it because that's permanent (create is transient):

```
virsh net-define /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/host-bridge.xml
```

Once the network is defined, the UUID will be added and then you can refer to it in a VM's XML file:

```
sudo grep -R "host-bridge" /etc/libvirt/
/etc/libvirt/qemu/Debian_7_x86.xml:      <source network='host-bridge'/>
/etc/libvirt/qemu/Debian_7_x64.xml:      <source network='host-bridge'/>
/etc/libvirt/qemu/Debian_8_x86.xml:      <source network='host-bridge'/>
/etc/libvirt/qemu/Debian_8_x32.xml:      <source network='host-bridge'/>
/etc/libvirt/qemu/Debian_8_x64.xml:      <source network='host-bridge'/>
...
```

It will also show up in the ***`networks/autostart`*** folder:

```
sudo grep -R "host-bridge" /etc/libvirt/
...
/etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/autostart/host-bridge.xml:  <name>host-bridge</name>
```

Finally, you should see similar to the following:

```
$ virsh net-list --all
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 host-bridge          inactive   yes           yes
```

Also see libvirt's [net-define](https://libvirt.org/sources/virshcmdref/html/sect-net-define.html) (permanent), [net-create](https://libvirt.org/sources/virshcmdref/html/sect-net-create.html) (transient) and [net-autostart](https://libvirt.org/sources/virshcmdref/html/sect-net-autostart.html).

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is just putting it in the same dir that I was running `sudo virsh net-create host-bridge` from.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].